# Framework for making a web-application who's content is managed

Tags: content-management-system, wiki

Is there a system (such as a development framework, Wiki or CMS) that enables you to build rich web applications, but where you can make all the text of the application content-managed?

For example, there might be screens that display charts and statistics, and a data entry form, and a form for modifying properties of something.

The unique code for each screen will be part of the application. However, content - i.e. paragraphs of 'help' text, headings, navigation - should all be managed.

By managed, I mean version controlled, and with an assigned access-level to specify who's allowed to modify the page.

Does anyone know of a system like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) allows for this.  Once you get into it, each individual element can be specified with full access control, and individual content elements on discrete pages can be "managed" individually as needed.